# can not receive email after server running few days

Tags: jakarta-mail, james

I had deployed apache james and a java mail application on business server. It works good about a week, but today, users complained that they can not receive new mail any more. I restart the server(the computer) and all solved.
I don't know what's going on, I doubt that it is the config of james because it gives a lot of Exceptions in logs:
    spoolmanager-2012-08-06-11-36.log

```
06/08/12 11:36:28 INFO  spoolmanager: Run JamesSpoolManager: Spool Thread #9
06/08/12 11:36:28 INFO  spoolmanager: Spool=$Proxy5
06/08/12 11:36:28 INFO  spoolmanager: Spool=$Proxy5
06/08/12 13:56:48 ERROR spoolmanager.transport: Exception calling LocalDelivery:
Exception spooling message: Exception caught while storing mail Container: 
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception spooling message: Exception caught while     storing mail Container: ;
nested exception is:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception caught while storing mail Container: ;
nested exception is:
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
The Connection descriptor used by the client was: 127.0.0.1:1521:spmmis
```

the config file is below:
[config.xml](http://www.cnblogs.com/ZhonghuaFY/archive/2012/08/07/2626164.html)

Comment: Is this the first time this has happened?

Comment: Yeah. It's the first time after server start running.

Comment: Probably bad luck, the moon and the stars missaligning with the code or something else.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot agree. There must a reason, maybe james, maybe oracle setting or my application. I just wanna find it out and fix it before it crash again.

Comment: The error-log is quite indescriptive, so anything from a full harddrive to a process geting stuck is a viable pick as reason.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just paste a few part of errors because the log is to large and full of the same error. All like javax.mail.MessagingException, java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error. Should I paste all of them? there are about 5 different log files with many errors.

Comment: Look for a resource leak, such as a file descriptor leak.  Make sure you close everything you open, especially on error paths.  Depending on your OS, you may be able to monitor file descriptor usage externally to the server.

Comment: Thank you @Bill Shannon. The code of receive email is: try{ folder.open(); //handle messages;  folder.close(false); }catch{logger.error();}. Should I move close to a finally block?